# Rails 4.2.9 "cannot load such file" (multiple files)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

So it's been a while since I fired up the old Rails server. It took a lot of tricks to even get the bundle to install... but eventually I upgraded from Rails 4.2.6 to 4.2.9. The bundle installs just fine. I'm on Ruby 2.3.0. But now the problem is... whenever I try to run:

```
rails s
```

I get the following error:

```
rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- loofah (LoadError)
    from /home/rainless/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails3.2.16/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rainless/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/rainless/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/rainless/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
```

Or some variation of that.

At first I was getting around this by uninstalling whatever the Gem that was said to be unable to load (in this case "loofah" but I've done it with many more), and then adding it to the Gemfile and installing it using Bundler. I now realize that the list is never-ending:

```
gem 'rails-html-sanitizer'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'multipart-post'
gem 'oauth-active-resource'
gem 'rack-test'
gem 'multi_json'
gem 'addressable'
gem 'orm_adapter'
```

All the above couldn't load. I ran Rails for years before this... and I know this isn't the way it's supposed to work. Any help/advice on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you see carefully in the error message, it says **ruby-2.3.0@rails3.2.16** but you mentioned "*upgraded from Rails 4.2.6 to 4.2.9.*" . For some reason, it's still referring to **rails3.2.16**. Therefore it could be you need to install the `rails-html-sanitizer` globally. By the way, Loofah is only needed if you wanted to use it in a non-rails app. Refer to the docs [here](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer).

> Rails Html Sanitizer is only intended to be used with Rails
>   applications. If you need similar functionality in non Rails apps
>   consider using Loofah directly (that's what handles sanitization under
>   the hood).

```
from /home/rainless/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails3.2.16/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Hahaha. Well that's just me being lazy. :) It's just the name of the gemset. Like I said... it was working fine in 4.2.6... so the name of the gemset has been "rails3.2.16" for a very, very long time and it always worked. rails-html-sanitizer is, indeed, installed globally. So no idea what's going on. Loofah is only the latest file that Rails said it couldn't load. I already added it and now it's telling me formtastic_i18n couldn't load. If I install that it'll tell me something else can't load. Still kinda lost on what the root problem is.